# Where to put smartgwt icons folder in project tree?

Tags: java, smartgwt

```
setNodeIcon("icons/person.png");
```

or

```
setIcon("icons/person.png");
```

In respectively SmartGWT `TreeGrid` and `Tab` (in `TabSet`) should find "person.png" in folder "icons" I guess but where should I put "icons" in the project itself?

In the JavaDoc it's also said that the default value for *setNodeIcon* is `[SKIN]file.gif` what does *[SKIN]* mean ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you find the default value (to my sense this use of the Skin folder is for using images already in the smartgwt skin)but any way I usually put my images directly in the war in my project with subfolder related to their size.
To use the icon I simply do for example `btnClear.setIcon("16/clear.png");
With war/images/16.clear.png image folders structure.`

You can have a look at `getSkinImgDir`and do a test